# Fixing before pseudo element after clicking

Tags: html, css

I try to make a dropdown information bar with + or - before it.
I don´t know how is it usually made but I came up with this try

```css
.test{
 width: 150px;
 height: 100px;
 background:gray;
}
.test:before{
 content: "+";
}
.test:active:before{
 content: "-";
}
```

```html
</div>
 <a href="#"><div class="test">
 Ahoj
 </div> </a>
```

¨

But I want it to stay on minus after clicking it because by clicking on it I rolldown other informations. 
Thanks for answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using javascript, you can do something similar using the `:target` selector.

https://codepen.io/partypete25/pen/xrbZmy

For it to work, the link itself needs to exist within the targeted content area.

```
.test:before {
  content: "+";
}

:target .test:before {
  content: "-";
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but if you click on it again it does not roll back, so I guess I need to do it with js. How is it called because I dont even know what to google so.

Comment: Using jQuery you can do that pretty easily. That's your best place to start. Here is link to an example using the toggleClass method: http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/